# Keyboard not working on Ubuntu 18.04 login screen

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, touchpad, tty, recovery-mode

My keyboard and mouse are not working on the login screen hence I can't enter my password and log in to the system.
I can enter into tty sesstion and recovery mode, and keyboard works there.
I reinstalled `xserver-xorg-input-all` package in recovery mode but it didn't solved the issue.

After installing `xserver-xorg-input-symantics`, my touchpad was working fine on the login screen but keyboard didn't.

I tried to use on screen keyboard to Login but It didn't open.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you get a prompt if you hit ctrl-alt-F2?

Comment: Nope, I didn't got any prompt.

Comment: Can you get into the bios by using the keyboard?

Comment: Yes, I can enter BIOS. I have found out that my touchpad is working because I had `xserver-xorg-input-symantics` package installed. once removed, touchpad also stopped working.

Comment: I should have specified can you get to any tty session via ctrl-alt-f3, trying all the way to f12?  I think that should be independent of X windows.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had this same problem and everything I searched and found did not work.

Ubuntu 20.04

**Problem:**
no login panel on the login screen>
mashing keys, did nothing
Mouse, did nothing.
I could use mouse and keyboard within the bios.
I could SSH in.
I was eventually able to hotkey force myself into ubuntu's terminal and keyboard was working in terminal, and I restarted x-windows or whatever and no change, no mouse no keyboard - still at square 1.

While searching the issue on my laptop on my other 3rd screen (extended from laptop).
I could not find the solution.
1 hour away from my desk and my laptop went to sleep and the laptops extended screen went into standby.
**Boom 3rd screen came up with ubuntu login.**

**Solution:**
I had 2 graphic ports/cables connected (only using one), and ubuntu had reset its display setup and had turned on the extra display, as primary.
but prior, my laptop was using that extra screen so ubuntu could not display the extended screen, but thought it was displaying.
So the 3rd screen had the login panel, and the mouse and keyboard were working just fine, and just could not see it.

**Route Cause:**
Ubuntu had added the extra display to my setup (without asking, following upgrade and reboot) and also made the 3rd screen the primary Ubuntu Screen. even though the screen was not set to that input (not ubuntu's fault)
Ubuntu's fault was changing my display setup on the back of an "sudo apt upgrade" and a reboot.

this may not be the askers answer, but it might help someone.

**Steps to take:**
Check to graphics cables first before re-installing software!